# I'm having difficulty parsing this json file

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse this json file that I recieved from an API call.

```
"[{\"ip\":\"xx.xx.xxx.xx\",\"dns\":\"xxx.net\",\"netbios\":\"xxxxx\",....
```

I dumped it to a file like so:

```
with open('jayo.json', 'w') as j:
    json.dump(r.text, j)          #r.text being the API response
```

json should just be a straightforward dictionary, right? why does mine have all the back-slashes?

How would I print each value on it's own? IP/DNS etc.

Comment: The back slashes look like they are escaping the `"` characters inside of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving the API response as a `str` you need to load it using json before dumping it. `json.dump` is usually used with collections not strings as it does the conversion for you.

```
data = json.loads(r.text)
with open('jayo.json', 'w') as j:
    json.dump(data, j)
```

If you need the data in the file before overwriting it load it use

```
with open('jayo.json', 'r') as j:
    data = json.load(j)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to load the JSON in Python, or dump it to a file?  (or both?)

`json.dump` is for writing a Python object to a JSON file.  `r.text` is just a string, so the resulting format will look like a single string in JSON (including all of the escaped quotes) instead of a full object.

Presumably you want to use `json.loads` to load the JSON string into a Python object before using `json.dump`.  Or if you want to dump the JSON string *straight* to a file, you can just use `j.write(r.text)`.